# Meaning of "inverse mold" in indirect 3D-printing

Tags: phrase-meaning

From "*[Printing Technologies for Medical Applications](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26856235)*":

> Indirect 3D printing has also been used to make and customize scaffolds for human mandibular reconstruction to create implants with materials which are easily printed[34]. Indirect printing consists of printing the **inverse molds** of the required configurations, and then casting the materials into the mold cavity[34]. In one report, gelatin was printed to make molds in the shape of the mandibular condyle.

I don't understand the meaning of "inverse" here. Why not just "mold"?

In 'direct 3D printing', we just print the organ, but with the indirect technology, we print a mold for that organ.

If we mold will be inverse, we would not be able to cast the material inside it, because the mold will already be in the form of the organ. A mold for making a mandibular condyle should be just 'mold', not 'inverse mold', IMHO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is regarding technical use of terminology (use of molds). The linguistic meaning of "inverse" is not at issue.

Comment: I don't think "inverse mold" is some rare technical usage. I think this is a valid question about whether there is a a difference between a mold and an inverse mold. Both inverse and mold are fairly common words separately and together; that the source of the question is technical shouldn't make the question off-topic.

Comment: I agree. The question is not about some recondite issue related to 3D printing per se, but about the application of a widely used term.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this question, it's a curious use of an adjective in an emphatic manner; but am too busy/lazy to ask at Meta what exactly should be considered 'too technical'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Molds' are often called 'inverses' of the things they are molds for, because their shape is the opposite of the finished product - having protrusions where the final object has holes, etc.

Occasaionally there can be 'positive molds', which are exactly like the thing going to be made. An inverse mold is cast from it, and then many copies of the positive mold made from that.

The writer says 'inverse mold' just to emphasize that it's the first type.

Answer (score 1):

[Mold](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mold) has several related meanings - specifying "inverse mold" or "reverse mold" just clarifies which of those meanings apply to the context.

1. a hollow form or matrix for giving a particular shape to something in a molten or plastic state.
2. the shape created or imparted to a thing by a mold.
3. something formed in or on a mold: a mold of jelly.
4. a frame on which something is formed or made.
5. shape or form.
6. a prototype, example, or precursor.

The first definition is by far the most common one - when you say mold, folks will think of either biological mold, like bread mold, or an inverse mold that you pour a liquid into that will harden into the thing you want to make. When it comes to certain casting processes, like [lost wax casting](http://www.americanbronze.com/process.html), there can be many intermediate "molds" some of which are positive and some of which are reverse. In a technical context "inverse mold" isn't quite as redundant as it seems if the author wants to be very clear about the type of mold that was created.